# AngularJS - Updating one element in ng-if causes all elements to get updated

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angluar2 and TypeScript to create a table. I couldn't figure out how to make the `<select>` in each `<td>` of the same row `<tr>` to be independent.  My codes would allow user to pick an option from any column.  Once a user pick an option, all columns in the same row will be updated.

```
<!--
    public _tableHeaders: Array of Object;
    public _rosters: Array of Object;
    public _dutyOptions: Array of Object;
-->

<div class="row">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:55px" *ngIf="_tableHeaders"></th>
        <!-- col for 'name'-->
        <th style="width:10px" *ngFor="let hdr of _tableHeaders">
          <div>{{hdr.DayOfMonth}}</div>
          <div>{{hdr.DayOfWeek}}</div>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let rosterList of _rosters">
        <template ngFor let-roster="$implicit" [ngForOf]="rosterList">
          <td *ngIf="roster.Switch == 'n'" style="width:55px">{{roster.DutyOption}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="roster.Switch == 'c'" style="width:55px">{{roster.DutyOption}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="roster.Switch == 'p'" style="width:10px">{{roster.DutyOption}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="roster.Switch == 'u' && roster.UserId != _userId" style="width:10px">{{roster.DutyOption}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="roster.Switch == 'u' && roster.UserId == _userId" style="width:10px">
            <select class="form-control input-sm" [ngModel]="_selDutyOption" (ngModelChange)="updateUserRequest($event, roster)">
              <option></option>
              <option *ngFor="let dutyOption of _dutyOptions; let j=index" (ngValue)="dutyOption" [selected]="dutyOption.Id === roster.DutyOptionId ? true : false">{{dutyOption.Description}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*each <td> of the same row <tr> to be independent*"? This sounds more like you're trying to do something in Angular, rather than in CSS...

Comment: In each row of the table, I have multiple columns.  Each column contains one "select/options".  Each "select/options" should be unique than the others.  When I choose an item from any one of the "select/options", the rest of "select/options" would get updated.  However, it should not happen.  The rest "select/options" should keep their original selected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you bind all the `select` elements with the same value:`_selDutyOption`, when one select changed, all will update.

Defining distinct models for each `select` element will solve your problem.

Comment: Pengyy, I think you are right. However, I don't know I could dynamically create the distinct models since I don't know the no. of columns and rows  in advance.

Comment: @Paul you can make a array, and add index varaible to the *ngFor expression, then bind array[index] with the select element. or there is another way which is add _selDutyOption to each item of your  _rosters and bind the select element with roster._selDutyOption by ngModel.

Comment: I implemented the option 2 by adding an additional field in the roster class [ngModel]="roster.SelValue". The display in the 'select/options' for all columns are correct now. However, it brought up a new problem which is the column that has new item being selected, is removed from the display. All columns from its right moved to the left.

Comment: I added an additional field in the roster class [ngModel]="roster.SelValue". The display in the 'select/options' for all columns are correct now. Thx for that. However, it brings up a new problem which is the column get new value is removed from the display. All cols from its right move to the left.  I noticed that [ngModel]="roster.SelValue" and [(ngModel)]="roster.SelValue" cause the editing column to be deleted and all cols from the right shift to left and fire the (ngModelChange).  (ngModel)="roster.SelValue" does not delete current col and also not fire (ngModelChange)

Comment: The problem of currently modify 'select/options' col disappeared is due the 'roster' in the updatedUserRequest function - (ngModelChange)='updatedUserRequest($event, roster)' - is being modified.  Copy the values of roster to a new Roster() object and then modify the new roster object inside the updatedUserRequest($event, roster) will solve the problem.  Thanks Pengyy for the help.